# What can we say about the transform of a function on a truncated domain, with respect to the transform on the full domain?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a function on R and $\hat f$ its Fourier transform.

Consider a truncated version of $f$ called $\bar f$ whose value outside an interval is $0$. Formally, $\bar f(x) = f(x) * 1_{x \in I}$ where $I$ is a closed interval.

What can we say about $F{\bar f}$, the Fourier transform of $\bar f$, with respect to the original transform $\hat f$?

I guess $F{\bar f} = \hat f \times F{1_{x\in I}}$ where $\times$ is the convolution operator. Can I have a **discrete** representation of $F{\bar f}$ as a function of $\hat f$?

Comment: What do you mean by a discrete representation?

Comment: You probably know that $F{1_{x\in I}}$ can be expressed with sinc function.

Comment: Yes, thanks I know for sinc. I was a bit unclear about my question regarding the discrete representation: I need to numerically compute the L2 scalar product of $F\bar f$ with some other function, and I'm not sure what grid to use. I guessed as the support in time-space is bounded, I could get some discrete sum in Fourier space rather than an integral, avoiding any arbitrary choice on the sampling grid. I'm new to Fourier so please tell me if this does not make sense.

Comment: Note that your "truncation" operator is a projection, i.e. $\langle \overline{f}, g\rangle = \langle \overline{f}, \overline{g}\rangle$. Now, since $\overline{f}$, $\overline{g}$ are supported on the interval $I$, you know that $F \overline{f}$ and $F \overline{g}$ are bandlimited, so that you can use Shannon's sampling theorem to compute the scalar product. The grid to use depends on the interval $I$.

Comment: Shannon's sampling theorem says if $h$ is band-limited, $h$ can be reconstructed from samples of $h$. You are asking a similar question: if $h$ is time-limited, can $Fh$ be reconstructed from samples of $Fh$ (i.e. represented discretely)? You should be able to alter this theorem to obtain your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this answers your question: Are you able to find/compute the inverse Fourier transform of the other function you are trying to take the $L^2$ inner product with? If your other function is $Fg \in L^2$, then by Parseval's Theorem you have that $\langle \bar{f} , g \rangle = \langle F\bar{f}, Fg \rangle$ (there may be a constant in front depending on which of the many versions of the Fourier transform you use). This avoids having to figure out what $Ff \star F1_I$ looks like as long as you can figure out what $g$ is and then you can use typical numerical integration techniques.

Comment: Thanks. I could use inverse fourier for getting $f$ from $\hat f$, then compute $\bar f$ from $f$ and finally transform back to $F\bar f$. I want to avoid that since it increases the complexity and does not make real sense in my context where I precisely try to minimize inversions. This is why I ask the question: is it easy to get an equivalent solution without transforming back and forth.